# Is it possible for Pipeline job parameters to change dynamically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to add or remove parameters for a job based on the value of other parameters?

For example, if there were a DEPLOY boolean parameter, could there then be a DEPLOY_LOCATION which is only visible if and when DEPLOY is set to TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. You can only use an `input` step.